# Clicking on question very slowly loads top bar

Tags: bug, ios-app

I don’t know what’s going on, but opening a question causes the top bar to very very slowly load in. So slow that sometimes it takes 5 seconds before I can hit the back button.

It’s like the animation has been slowed down dramatically.

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: iPhone 7 Plus
- OS Version: Version 13.1.2 (Build 17A860)

Comment: in case you didn't come across it, apps are currently on a low priority in development phase. Several comments and answers confirm this.

Comment: Good to know. Figured I’d report anyway. Low impact bug, restarting app fixed it

Comment: I think I’ve seen this but it doesn’t happen every time. But then again I usually take more than 5 seconds to read a question, so I’m not looking at the top bar :P

Comment: I’m a very fast reader ;)